# How to detect upload progress and upload status in Alamofire 5 with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

In document of alamorefire, It have only this example for detect a upload progress

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    multipartFormData.append(Data("one".utf8), withName: "one")
    multipartFormData.append(Data("two".utf8), withName: "two")
}, to: "https://httpbin.org/post").responseDecodable(of: HTTPBinResponse.self) { response in
        debugPrint(response)
}
```

But my expectation is I want to detect its upload progress and upload status after it done like some result

```
switch result {
    case .success():
       //Success code
       break

    case .failure:
       //show error upload failed
       break
}
```

Comment: Help yourself by running a simple search engine search for swift alamofire progress upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :-

```
    AF.upload(multipartFormData: { MultipartFormData in
            MultipartFormData.append(fileContent, withName: "file" , fileName: filePath.lastPathComponent , mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            for(key,value) in dictonary {
                MultipartFormData.append(token.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: "token")
            }
        }, to: uploadURL, method: .post, headers: ["Content-Type": "application/json")
    
            .uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })
    
            .responseJSON{ (response) in
                debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
             }
        }
```